# Is there any way to remove Sharepoint online 365 black ribbon and grey bar (suite bar and ribbon bar) for the users?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I am creating intranet site in sharepoint online 2013 and the requirement is to remove those two bar. But this is first time developing site in 2013 online, it would make my job little hard if there is no suite bar or ribbon bar.

So does anyone have idea how can I remove those two bars for all users but not for the site owners?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish by custom css styling

Please have a look at this post.

http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2015/09/stack-suite-bar-on-ribbon-sharepoint-online/